# How to set 127.0.0.1 as a proxy for firefox

Tags: firefox, proxy, burp

I'm trying to set 127.0.0.1 as a proxy for Firefox (for use with burp suit) as shown as below picture. But it is not working. The browser is continuously showing the message `"The proxy server is refusing connections"` What should I do? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Is the proxy running at all? Can you check if the port is correct and you can use the proxy from another application?

Answer (score 0):

In browser, you have set proxy port no as **3128** and in Burp **default port is 8080** for proxy setting. Make sure that both ports are same and also verify the same in FoxyProxy or other addon if used for proxy.

To change Burp proxy settings, Open Burp Suite, and change proxy settings from **Option** button in **Proxy** menu.